# Mean residual life function limits

Tags: probability, limits, statistics, probability-distributions, risk-assessment

In my paper about mean residual life functions and heavy tails I've come across the examples listed in the picture below.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnklD.png
- source (page 124/125): http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~schmidli/vorl/Risk/vorl.pdf

I've managed to successfully calculate the limits when $M \rightarrow\infty$ for the Exponential and Pareto distribution myself using the  equation $$\frac{\int_M^\infty {(1-F(z))dz}}{1-F(M)}$$ however I fail to understand how to calculate the remaining three (marked in yellow). I am new to probability so please bear with me. Thank you for your aid.

Comment: I have not try but what have you got when you apply L'Hôpital's rule to the limit?

Comment: That yields the correct result when used on the Weibull distribution, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it on the remaining two. Also how do you know that the numerator converges to 0 or infinity (so you may apply L'Hôpital)?

Comment: I think it is quite obvious that it is the $\frac {0} {0}$ form (I may not be rigorous enough to claim the numerator directly; but at least the denominator is following the definition). The remaining work is just differentiation and applying the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us write the formulas themselves.  As I come from an actuarial background, my notation is slightly different:  $$\overset\circ e_m = \operatorname{E}[T-m \mid T > m] = \frac{\int_{t=m}^\infty S(t) \, dt}{S(m)} = \int_{t=0}^\infty \vphantom._t p_m \, dt$$ where $T$ is the lifetime random variable, $S(t) = 1 - F(t)$ is the survival function of $T$, and $\vphantom._t p_m = S(m+t)/S(m)$ is the probability of survival of a life aged $m$ to age $m+t$.  The key observation is that as $m \to \infty$, both the numerator and denominator tend to $0$, so L'Hopital's rule applies.  Then by the fundamental theorem, and noting $S(\infty) = 0$:  $$\lim_{m \to \infty} \overset\circ e_m = \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{-S(m)}{-f(m)} = \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{-f(m)}{f'(m)},$$ where $f$ is the density of $T$.  Now all that remains is to choose a density:  for a gamma distribution with shape $\gamma$ and rate $\alpha$, we have $$f(m) \propto m^{\gamma-1} e^{-\alpha m},$$ consequently $$f'(m) \propto (\gamma - 1)m^{\gamma-2} e^{-\alpha m} - m^{\gamma - 1} \alpha e^{-\alpha m} = m^{\gamma - 2} e^{-\alpha m} (\gamma - 1 - \alpha m).$$  Hence $$\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{-f(m)}{f'(m)} = \frac{m}{\alpha m + 1 - \gamma},$$ and as $m \to \infty$, this is clearly $1/\alpha$ as claimed.  A similar approach works for the other two distributions.  If you remain stuck in the calculation, I will amend this answer to include those computations.

Comment: This was the final piece that was missing in my understanding of the problem, thank you very much.